# AngularJs resource.query returns Expected response to contain an query but got an array

Tags: angularjs, node.js, amazon-dynamodb, angular-resource

I am really confused. 
I am trying to do a query on some data using a resource

```
var Spot = $resource('/api/spot');
Spot.query({username: $rootScope.currentUser.data.username}, function (results) {
    $scope.storage.push(results);
});
```

The route is defined in Express:

```
app.get('/api/spot', function (req, res){        
DB.scan().where('username').equals(req.query.username).exec(function(err, result) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err)
            res.sendStatus(500);
        } else {
            console.log(util.inspect(_.map(result.Items, 'attrs')));
            res.send(util.inspect(_.map(result.Items, 'attrs')));
        };
    });
});
```

which returns an array e.g. (copied from the response tab from Chrome)

```
[ { date: '2017-11-07:14:44:36', truck: 'ZXC', username: 'asdf' },
  { date: '2017-11-07:14:47:24',
  truck: 'banana',
  username: 'asdf' } 
]
```

And prints to the nodejs console:

```
[ { date: '2017-11-07:14:44:36', truck: 'ZXC', username: 'asdf' },
{ date: '2017-11-07:14:47:24',
truck: 'banana',
username: 'asdf' } ]
```

However Angular is throwing an error saying that it expected a query and got an array,  I though the point of query was to expect and array (and get to expect and object).

Can anyone see what I am doing wrong (other than not having a clue about Angular :D )

Comment: Where exactly are you getting the error?  Is it in the `query()` callback or the `$scope.storage.push(results);`?  Additionaly, I don't know that you want to push an Array into an Array.  That would give you nested Arrays: `["a", "b", ["a", "b"]]`.  You probably wanted to concat to get: `["a", "b", "a", "b"]`.  See the difference?

Comment: I believe the error is coming from the Query as it doesn't get into the callback function.
Good shout on the array concat as well! Thanks